# How to Convert Text to Speech Audio to Audio data array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want make audio visualization on Reactjs from text sound, I have converted text to Speech using speechSynthesis. Now, I want this speech in a data array form to generate Audio visualization bars using Canvas. 
Please guide or do you have any other suggestion?

I have converted text to speech using speechSynthesis and done audio visualization with data in array from microphone source. now I want arrayData of textToSpeech sound.

```
    //code to convert microphone audio to data array
    this.audioContext = new (window.AudioContext ||
    window.webkitAudioContext)();
    this.analyser = this.audioContext.createAnalyser();
    this.dataArray = new Uint8Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    this.source =                                     
    this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.props.audio);
    this.source.connect(this.analyser);
    this.rafId = requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);
    //code to convert text to speech
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    msg.voice = voices[9];
    msg.voiceURI = "native";
    msg.volume = 1;
    msg.rate = 1;
    msg.pitch = 0.8;
    msg.text = "Heloo world";
    msg.lang = 'en-US';
    this.setState({aud: speechSynthesis.speak(msg)})
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

I want to generate Text to Speech sound in data array so I can make audio 
 visualization of that.